# string to integer

Tags: c++, string

I can't do this in C++

```
string temp = "123";
int t = atoi(temp);
```

why????

Comment: A lot of the answers have said you can't do it because the function takes a const char* so call .c_str(). Fair enough, and correct. But I would ask the question why haven't all the functions that take a const char* been overloaded in c++ to take a const std::string& too, it seems like that would have been an obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 8):

That is because `atoi` is expecting a raw `const char*` pointer. Since there is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to `const char*` you get a compiler error. Use `c_str()` method of `std::string` to get a c-style `const char*` for a std::string object. BTW, in C++ you can use streams to do this conversion instead of using these C-style APIs.

Answer (score 6):

```
atoi(temp.c_str())
```

Answer (score 3):

See these questions:

[C atoi() string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488569/c-atoi-string-to-int): Points out that atoi() is deprecated.

[Why doesn't C++ reimplement C standard functions with C++ elements style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771117/why-doesnt-c-reimplement-c-standard-functions-with-c-elements-style): Gives alternate ways to do what you've listed above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you passed a std::string (presumably) to atoi, which takes a const char*. Try:

```
atoi(temp.c_str());
```

which was previously mentioned. Instead, you could use boost's [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm):

```
std::string temp = "123";
try {
   int foo = boost::lexical_cast<int>(temp);
} catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast e) {
   //handle error here
}
```

You could wrap the try/catch into a template function that handles the exceptions in the event that you do not already have exception handling in place.

Answer (score 0):

std::string is not the same as a character pointer (like in C).

Answer (score -1):

```
int i = 12345;

std::string s;

std::stringstream sstream;

sstream << i;

sstream >> s;
```

Comment: This is int to string. He want string to int.