# Convert std::string to MSVC specific __int64

Tags: c++

May I know how I can convert std::string, to MSVC specific __int64?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[_atoi64, _atoi64_l, _wtoi64, _wtoi64_l](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czcad93k%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
std::string str = "1234";
__int64 v =_atoi64(str.c_str());
```

See also this link (although it is for linux/unix): [Why doesn't C++ reimplement C standard functions with C++ elements/style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771117/why-doesnt-c-reimplement-c-standard-functions-with-c-elements-style/1771471#1771471)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s( "1234567890987654321");

    stringstream strm( s);

    __int64 x;

    strm >> x;

    cout << x;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`__int64`, while an extension, is still just a numeric type. Use whichever method you would typically use.

Boost [lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) is my favorite. It pretty much wraps up Michaels answer in an easy to use form:

```
__int64 x = boost::lexical_cast<__int64>("3473472936");
```

If you can't use boost, you can still do a pretty good job of making a simple version. Here's an implementation I wrote for another answer:

```
template <typename R>
const R lexical_cast(const std::string& s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    R result;
    if ((ss >> result).fail() || !(ss >> std::ws).eof())
    {
        throw std::bad_cast();
    }

    return result;
}
```

It does some extras, like checking for trailing characters. (`"123125asd"` would fail). If the cast cannot be made, `bad_cast` is thrown. (Similar to boost.)

Also, if you have access to boost, you can avoid the need to use the MSVC-specific `__int64` extension with:

```
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
typedef boost::int64_t int64;
```

To get `int64` on any platform that provides it, without changing your code.