# C++: what benefits do string streams offer?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

could any one tell me about some practical examples on using string streams in c++, i.e. inputing and outputing to a string stream using stream insertion and stream extraction operators?

Comment: You mean cin and cout? As opposed to C-style getc and printf?

Comment: @Vanessa: OP probably means `std::stringstream`, (`#include <sstream>`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use string streams to convert anything that implements `operator <<` to a string:

```
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
std::string toString(const T& t)
{
  std::ostringstream stream;
  stream << t;

  return stream.str();
}
```

or even

```
template <typename U, typename T>
U convert(const T& t)
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << t;

  U u;
  stream >> u;

  return u;
}
```

Comment: Just remember that this solution will only work for primitive types and overloaded versions of `operator<<` with specific classes.

Comment: @fogo: And since it is relatively common to define streaming operators for classes, that is not such a big deal.

Comment: @Martin York Indeed, I just considered a proper comment considering the *convert anything* remark in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I use them mostly as memory buffers, in creating messages:

```
if(someVector.size() > MAX_SIZE)
{
    ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << "Vector should not have " << someVector.size() << " eleements";
    throw std::runtime_error(buffer.str());
}
```

or to construct complex strings:

```
std::string MyObject::GenerateDumpPath()
{
    using namespace std;

    std::ostringstream      dumpPath;

    // add the file name
    dumpPath << "\\myobject."
        << setw(3) << setfill('0') << uniqueFileId
        << "." << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(state)
        << "_" << ymd.year 
        << "." << setw(2) << setfill('0') << ymd.month.as_number()
        << "." << ymd.day.as_number()
        << "_" << time.hours() 
        << "." << time.minutes() 
        << "." << time.seconds()
        << ".xml";

    return dumpPath.str();
}
```

It is useful because it brings all the extensibility of `std::stream`s to using character buffers (ostreams extensibility and locales support, buffer memory management is hidden and so on).

Another example I've seen was the error reporting in gsoap library, using dependency injection: [soap_stream_fault](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#MwAbMLANvWg/gapiservice/server/stdsoap/stdsoap2.cpp&q=soap_stream_fault&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=15069) takes an ostream& parameter to report error messages in.

If you want you can pass it std::cerr, std::cout or an std::ostringstream implementation (I use it with a std::ostringstream implementation).

Answer (score 2):

Besides advantages there is [one point to carefully consider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771117/why-doesnt-c-reimplement-c-standard-functions-with-c-elements-style/1771471#1771471) if you use gcc 4.3.1. I didn't checked preceding versions of gcc.

Comment: This was an limitation of a specific implementation (gcc). It you follow the link through to the bugzilla bug associated with he problem you will also note that the bug has been marked resolved <qoute>the mutex is not used anymore</quote>

Comment: Then it is great! I will edit my post in order to add information what this information is relevant only to some versions of gcc.

Answer (score 2):

They can be used anywhere a normal stream can be used.

So in situations where you were reading from a file you could potentially read from a string stream.

```
void compile(std::istream& str)
{
    CPlusPlusLexer   lexer(str);
    CPlusPlusParser  parser(lexer);
    BackEnd          backend(parser);

    backend.compile();
}

int main()
{
    std::fstream   file("Plop.cpp");
    compile(file);

    std::stringstream  test("#include <iostream>\n int main() { std::cout << \"H World\n\";}");
    compile(test);
}
```